# remove key from ~/.ssh/authorized_key

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any tool to fish out the ssh-key from the list, like `ssh-copy-id` does given identity file, or we have todo write down custom script.

Comment: No handy ways, see https://superuser.com/questions/429954/command-to-remove-a-ssh-authorized-key-on-server

Comment: Is the scenario one where you have a local identity file and you want to remove that entry from a *remote* authorized_keys file?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes i need to remove keys from multiple server, now i have to log in and remove it one by one.